# Go cgo ldap_init could not determine kind of name for C.ldap_init

Tags: c, go, ldap, cgo

I was trying to learn and understand cgo. 
I am writing a program in Go where I connect to AD and parse the output. I tested the code in C, which is working fine as expected. The relevant part in `C` is

```
char *ldap_host = "x.x.x.x";
int   ldap_port     = 389;
ldap = ldap_init(ldap_host, ldap_port))
```

Now I am trying to get the same working in go as

```
//#cgo CFLAGS: -lldap 
//#include <ldap.h>
import "C"
func main() {
    var hostname *string
    hostname = &os.Args[1]
    ldap_port := 389
    ldap := C.ldap_init(*hostname, ldap_port)
}
```

But I am getting the following error

```
could not determine kind of name for C.ldap_init
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by getting the basics of Go and cgo working before adding the individual peculiarities of a library like ldap. Some good starting points, especially the official cgo doc page.

- https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/
- http://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo
- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo

Starting from the top:

You don't need the `CFLAGS` here, but you will need `LDFLAGS` for the linker, and `liblber` for this to run.

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lldap -llber
```

You can't pass a pointer to a Go string as a C `*char`, they are different types. Strings in Go actually aren't addressable at all, so this would be a compile error if the build process got that far. Use `C.CString`, and `C.free` if you need to create C strings. You will also need to include `stdlib.h` for `C.free`.

```
    url := C.CString(os.Args[1])
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(url))
```

Go's `int` size varies by architecture, and is not C's `int` type. `ldap_port` in your example is converted to the default type of `int`, where you would have needed `C.int`.

Finally, the original error in your question has nothing to do with Go or cgo. The `ldap_init` function is deprecated, and does not exist without setting `LDAP_DEPRECATED`. You should use the `ldap_initialize` function. Here is a minimal example that compiles:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "unsafe"
)

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ldap.h>

#cgo LDFLAGS: -lldap -llber
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    url := C.CString("ldap://127.0.0.1:389/")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(url))

    var ldap *C.LDAP

    rv := C.ldap_initialize(&ldap, url)
    if rv != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("ldap_initialize() error %d", rv)
    }
    log.Println("initialized")
}
```

Comment: Thank you @JimB. Appreciate the pointers on where to learn this.

Comment: I wonder if this is 100% safe. From what I could understand in [#12416](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12416) and [#8310](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8310), it is incorrect to pass Go pointer to C function when you don't know if the Go pointer will be kept by C side.

I don't expect ldap to do this, but would it not be more safe to C.malloc that pointer (*LDAP, not LDAP)?

Comment: @TomaszKłak: This is fine. #8310 is irrelevant, and was superseded by  #12416. The memory for `ldap` here is allocated in C when passing a `**C.LDAP`, where the pointer itself is filled in by the C code, pointing to C memory. The go1.6 cgo checks are enabled by default, and will crash the program rather than allow potentially unsafe behavior.

Comment: Oh, you did check this under 1.6. I know that memory allocated by `ldap_initialize` was not a problem here. What I was worried about is that `ldap_initialize` might store adress of Go variable `ldap` somewhere in some global C value. That would lead to C having pointer to Go value after C call ended.

Comment: @TomaszKłak: My local go build is only a couple days old from master. Even if the value of `ldap` is stored in C, it's not a pointer to Go memory. It starts off as `nil`, and is filled in by the initialize function. So what you have is a pointer value on the Go heap, pointing to C memory, which we've deemed safe. It's just as if `ldap_initialize` returned an `*LDAP` which we assign to `ldap`, but since C doesn't have multiple return values or exceptions, it's common to pass a `**` as a parameter instead.